# .size() string manipulation not reading actual length/size of characters c++

Tags: c++, string, iostream, file-handling

I am trying to read in an essay from a file which I then need to change each beginning letter of a sentence to an upper case letter and then send the corrected essay back to a file called correct.txt. The essay is stored in essay.txt.

So far I am just working with understanding the conversions from files to string in order for me to proceed with the rest of the question. So far, I have a string variable which which holds the essay with the words separated by a single space. I noticed that when I was trying to work with the size of my new string, it was not giving me the correct answer and I cannot figure out why. If you have any suggestions on how I can get it to notice the correct amount of characters, I would really appreciate it.

One more question while you're here, I know that moving forward, in order to change the beginning letters of the sentence to upper case, I need to first find the periods. Once I have this position, I can use pos+2 (including the preceding whitespace after the period) for the character that needs to become upper case. Is this the correct way of going about this and do you have any other tips on how to go forward with this?

Here is my code so far:

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream> 
    #include <string>
    #include <cstdlib>
    using namespace std;

    int main(){

      //declaring variables and creating objects
      ifstream inputFile;
      ofstream outputFile;
      char inputFileName[20], outFileName[20];

       cout << "Enter name of the file you want to open: " << endl;
       cin >> inputFileName;

       inputFile.open(inputFileName);
       if (inputFile.fail()) {

         cout << "Input file opening failed.\n";
         exit(1);
      }

       cout << "Enter name of the file you want to send the output to: " << endl;
       cin >> outFileName;

       outputFile.open(outFileName);
       if (outputFile.fail()) {

         cout << "Output file opening failed.\n";
         exit(1);
    }

     //while the file is open, it sends the contents to the string variable "essay"
     string essay;
     inputFile >> essay;

     while (!inputFile.eof()) {

       cout << essay << " "; 
       inputFile >> essay;

     }

     //this is to check for the correct size of the string "essay" before moving on to the rest of the code
     int size = essay.size();
     cout << size << endl;

     return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Your `essay` variable contains the last whitespace separated word when the loop is terminated. Is that what you want?

Comment: Why not use getline instead of cin and file >>?

Comment: You should post the exact input you supplied along with the output you got

Comment: It would be a good idea to use `string` instead of `char[20]` so that you do not get undefined behaviour if the filenames exceed 19 chars

Comment: Let me know whether my code solves ur issue , remember #include <cstring>

Comment: It does make more sense to have a string variable, i have just been so used to seeing tutorials using char[] instead so I guess i just caught onto that. I also changed my loop to use get line instead of cin which was easier. Thank you for all your advice.

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding of how the input stream works is incorrect.

The core of your code is this loop:

```
string essay;
inputFile >> essay;
while (!inputFile.eof()) {
  cout << essay << " "; 
  inputFile >> essay;
}
```

What this does is that it reads the first word into `essay`, then, as long as the eof marker is not set on the stream it echoes back the word just read, and then reads another word, **overwriting the previous one**.

Here's the correct code. Note that checking for eof in a loop condition is a bad idea, because it doesn't quite do what you want, and would also get you stuck in an infinite loop if the stream instead entered an error condition.

```
string word;
while (inputFile >> word) { // read a word and stop if this fails for any reason
  essay += word;
  essay += " ";
}
```

Though I'm not sure why you read the file word by word instead of all at once.

Also, I feel the need to repeat what M.M. said in a comment: your use of raw character arrays on input is *unsafe* and *unnecessary*. Just use `string`. You need to then write `inputFile.open(inputFileName.c_str())` unless your standard library is new enough to have the `string` overloads of these functions, but that is fine. The other way of doing it is dangerous and a very bad habit to get into.

Comment: Thank you, very helpful! I changed my code to read the whole file instead of word for word, as I see you mentioned it in your comment. `if (inputFile.is_open()) {

  while (inputFile.good()) {
   getline(inputFile, essay);
   cout << essay << endl;
  }
 }`

Answer (score -1):

Try include cstring on top of string as well.
String is considered char array which is a more 'unique' way of storing data. You can try the code listed below.

```
int size = essay.length();
```